# How do I create a view with multiple aggregated functions?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, sql-view

How do I create a new view name as FULLVIEW. And get the following column: MIN(LASTNAME) name as NAME, DISTINCT (MANAGER_ID) rename as “Available Manager_id”, COUNT (MANAGER_ID) rename as “No. of Manager_id”,  and the SUM(SALARY) per job_id. And apply Full Outer Join
Doing all possible way in order to create the FULLVIEW view, without swapping the columns.

I can't seem to figure out how to do this because I'm kind of new to SQL. My boss gave me this exercise for a project. This is actually the last of the exercise and this is the only one I can't figure out.

I got two tables available:

- Departments
- Employees

I have been trying to do this, but can't really figure it out.

```
    SQL> CREATE VIEW FULLVIEW AS
  2  SELECT LASTNAME, EMPLOYEES.MANAGER_ID, DEPARTMENTS.MANAGER_ID, SALARY
  3  FROM EMPLOYEES
  4  FULL OUTER JOIN
  5  (
  6  SELECT LASTNAME, MIN('LASTNAME') AS NAME
  7  FROM EMPLOYEES)
  8  (
  9  SELECT DISTINCT MANAGER_ID 'AVAILABLE MANAGER_ID'
 10  FROM EMPLOYEEES)
 11  (
 12  SELECT COUNT MANAGER_ID 'NO. OF MANAGER_ID'
 13  FROM EMPLOYEEES)
 14  (
 15  SELECT SUM SALARY FOR EACH ROW
 16  FROM EMPLOYEES);
```

Comment: You should take some elementary tutorial on SQL and practice on those themas: 1) how to join two tables, 2) how to aggregate using GROUP BY - before you apply for a job as an SQL expert;)

Comment: Please show sample columns and rows for your result. So far I have no idea, what you are trying. You want all distinct manager IDs? And the one last name in the table that comes first in alphabet? How does that get into one result table? Then `SUM` and `COUNT` are functions, not mere keywords, you need parentheses. Then MIN('LASTNAME') is 'LASTNAME' - it doesn't matter how often you have the string 'LASTNAME', the minimum (and maximum) value is still 'LASTNAME'. Then, you join without `USING` or `ON` clauses. Even without `JOIN` clauses. It actually looks like you never wrote any query so far.

Comment: And anyway, it's just an exercise. If you cannot solve it, you know where you stand and what to practise.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber actually i did not apply for this job, my boss assigned me here.

Comment: As mentioned, I don't understand what you are trying to achieve. I don't understand your explanation. And it seems that others have the same problem, for SQL questions usually get several answers within minutes. What you should do is show sample data: some employee rows, some department rows and then the rows of the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use double quotation marks for column aliases and the "as" keyword. For example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT MANAGER_ID AS "AVAILABLE MANAGER_ID"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE VIEW FULLVIEW
  AS ( 
    SELECT MIN(LASTNAME) AS NAME,
           DISTINCT(E.MANAGER_ID) AS "Available Manager_id", 
           COUNT(E.MANAGER_ID) AS "No.of Manager_id",
           JOB_ID, 
           sum(salary)
      FROM EMPLOYEES E 
        FULL OUTER JOIN DEPARTMENTS D ON E.DEPARTMENT_ID = D.DEPARTMENT_ID
      GROUP BY JOB_ID);
```